# Check error with 20.04-desktop ISO

Tags: usb, live-usb, iso, disk-check

When using the ISO for Ubuntu 20.04, checking the SHA256SUM (from here - https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/SHA256SUMS), and creating a bootable USB, the following message appears briefly at the end of the media check during boot.

```
Check finished: errors found in 1 files! You might encounter errors.
```

I tried creating the bootable USB with 3 different thumbdrives (2 different brands), and using either the Startup Disk Creator or Disks and the error does not go away.

Could the ISO be corrupted ? (and the checksum be calculated on the corrupted iso).

**edit:** a comment requested further clarification on that latest part -  The check during boot appears to be checking individual files (in the ISO) while the checksum verfied after downloading (and prior to creating the bootable USB) is for the ISO. The creation of the ISO and the calculation of its digest, and the check mechanisms for individual files in the ISO can be distinct processes, which would allow the creation of a corrupted ISO if being built from at least one corrupted subpart (file).

Comment: Please,  expand your last sentence by making it clearer. If the checksum of the iso file is correct, then the iso should be ok.

Comment: Did you check the checksums on the .iso file that you downloaded?

Comment: @heynnema : as the mentioned in the question, I did check the sha256 checksum.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli - Let me know if this is clearer now. I am not familiar with the build process for ISOs (which is why this is a question).

Comment: I tried with a third brand of USB drive. It looks like a issue so I am moving to Launchpad. I will delete this entry in ask Ubuntu.

Comment: If the SHA256SUM for the .iso matched, then the .iso download is good. When booting the USB flash, that checking is only for the files on the USB flash. It sounds like you've got a bunch of possibly bad USB flashes, or maybe something else on your USB bus is not allowing a clean burn to the USB flash drives. Disconnect all unnecessary USB devices and try again.

Comment: 4 drives from 3 different brands x 2 different USB ports x 2 different programs. This would be be an impressively reproducible outcome for a suspected hard-to-reproduce issue. ;-)

Comment: I might be right and the official Ubuntu ISO has a problem (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

I checked all files in the ISO individually matched the MD5 checksum with the list of checksums in the ISO: the checksum does not match for one file: `./boot/grub/efi.img`.

This means that the ISO is incorrect. I filed an issue report on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1888033